# nhibernate automapping with union-subclass option

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I want to (auto)map a base class and its derived class to two different tables, as described [here](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/04/10/nhibernate-mapping-ndash-inheritance.aspx) by ayende (unioned subclasses).
however, according to fluent nHibernate's documentation, I don't see a way do do that.
the property in IAutoMappingOverride they refer to is "IsDiscriminated", but that only difrrentiates between table-per-heirarchy and table-per-subclass.
Is it possible that automapping doesn't support unioned subclasses? and if so- can anyone suggest a workaround?
thanks,
Jhonny

Comment: 5 years later.. did you ever figure this one out? I would also like to know a solution to this without writing too many overrides!

Comment: Wow, so much time has passed I don't think I even understand my own question anymore...  
In any case, I think these days NHibernate has its own mapping by code feature, so you're probably better off using that.  
Sorry I'm not able to provide more help...

Comment: No worries, thanks for you help! Settled on a different solution in the end anyway